# Largest sequence of prime numbers from array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm new to python and I'm trying to figure out the largest sequence of prime numbers from an array. 
I wrote a function to figure if a number is prime or not and using this I'm trying to find the largest sequence of prime numbers in an array.

For example:

array1 = [1,2,5,4,2,2,3,4]

For this array, the largest sequence of prime numbers is 2,2,3. 
To figure this I tried using this approach:

```
def primeSequence(s):
    l=[]
    k=[]
    j=0
    for i in range(1,len(s)+1):

        if isPrime(s[i]):  
            l.append(s[i])
        else:
            break
    print(l)    
    k.append(l)
    print(k);
```

Basically, I went through the array and check if the number is prime. If it is, I store it in an array. Then that array I store it in another array and in the end the plan was to go through that k array and find which array is the largest.

The problem is that the for loop breaks when it find the 4 (which is not prime) and I don't know how to traverse the array again from that point..
I'm not sure if I was clear enough.. Any suggestions how can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
def primeSequence(s):
    l=[]
    k=[]
    j=0
    max_l = []                       #store the max sequence at present

    for i in range(len(s)):

        if isPrime(s[i]):  
            l.append(s[i])
        else:
            if len(l)>len(max_l):     #is longest primeSequence
              max_l = l               #store that
            l=[]                      #for starting new primeSequence series

    if len(l)>len(max_l):             #handles case where the sequence includes the last element
          max_l = l

    print(max_l)
```

Few things. For finding the max sequence, you need to store the values of the present max sequence in another variable and check if the present sequence `len` is greater than the max sequence `len`. The `else` part is used as a marker that the present prime sequence has **ended** and this is where you **check** if what you have now is the greater sequence.

Comment: There is not an index problem at s[i] when i reaches len(s)?

Comment: I asummed the OP is handling it. But yes. I'll change it.

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to say that I get this error:
IndexError: list index out of range. It works now, thanks a lot. I'll mark the answer in a few min.

Comment: @OvidiuG , glad to help